# Angular Material styles not being applied correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

Any ideas why the angular material styles are not being applied correctly?

I know there are a lot of questions on this but I can't seem to find one that resolved my problem.
I have used angular material with no problem for several projects but can't seem to figure out what is going on here.
I am probably overlooking something simple but just can't see it.  I have just upgraded to angular 7 so it could be related to that.

This is my dialog which just displays in the parent page with weird or no styling.  It is doing something as the buttons have changed slightly as you can see compared to the cancel button.

[image]

```
<div>
  <h4 mat-dialog-title>New Course Item</h4>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <div>
        <div>
          <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
              <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newCourseItem.title" #title="ngModel" matInput required placeholder="Title" name="title"/>
              <mat-error *ngIf="title.hasError('required')">This field is required</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button (click)="this.dialogRef.close()">Cancel</button>
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [mat-dialog-close]="newCourseItem" cdkFocusInitial>Add New</button>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

import { CourseItem } from './../../../../models/course-item';
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-course-item-dialog',
  templateUrl: './new-course-item-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-course-item-dialog.component.css']
})
export class NewCourseItemDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  newCourseItem: CourseItem = new CourseItem();

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewCourseItemDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { MatInputModule, MatDialogModule, MatButtonModule, MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    CourseAdminComponent,
    NewCourseItemDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    DataService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    NewCourseItemDialogComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }


Angular CLI: 7.0.5
Node: 10.7.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.0.4
... animations, cdk, common, core, material

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.10.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular       0.10.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer     0.10.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack       0.10.5
@angular-devkit/core                7.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics          7.0.5
@angular/cli                        7.0.5
@angular/compiler                   7.0.3
@angular/compiler-cli               7.0.3
@angular/flex-layout                7.0.0-beta.19
@angular/forms                      7.0.3
@angular/http                       7.0.3
@angular/language-service           7.0.3
@angular/platform-browser           7.0.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   7.0.3
@angular/router                     7.0.3
@ngtools/webpack                    7.0.5
@schematics/angular                 7.0.5
@schematics/update                  0.10.5
rxjs                                6.3.3
typescript                          3.1.6
webpack                             4.19.1
```

Comment: Have you included the CSS file in your angular.json file?

Comment: Add `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";` to your styles.css if you haven't already.

Comment: You guys are the best.  Thanks!  So obvious I guess, but I realise now that I used angular material in an existing project so didn't have to apply this step.  Never again.

Comment: Adding the import worked for me too

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The comments from @user18994 and @SiddAjmera answered this.

> **Step 4: Include a theme**
>
> Including a theme is required to apply all of the core and theme
>   styles to your application.
>
> To get started with a prebuilt theme, include one of Angular
>   Material's prebuilt themes globally in your application. If you're
>   using the Angular CLI, you can add this to your styles.css:
>
> `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`
>
> If you are not using the Angular CLI, you can include a prebuilt theme
>   via a  element in your index.html.
>
> For more information on theming and instructions on how to create a
>   custom theme, see the theming guide.

Source:
https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Comment: I used Angular CLI and selected a dark purple/amber theme. the table was messed up not only that it did not actually get imported in my angular project not sure maybe a bug in their npm tool? Your answer made me recheck that and there I found the culprit.

Comment: There are ways to miss this theme import. In my case, I created an empty workspace, added a library, and then added an app project. I went back and ran `ng add @angular/material`, I entered a default theme in the interactive generator, but it never added the theme import to the styles.scss file. After I added that manually, material components looked right.

Comment: In the documentation it's said that you don't need to do anything apart for Angular Material to work, it isn't mentioned that you have to import the theme. Too bad!

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes missing imports in app.module.ts causes this issue.
Make sure you have imported all the modules which you have used in your HTML.

As per latest angular material documentation you have to import modules from its respective package instead of @angular/material/

So instead of

```
import { MatToolbarModule , MatButtonModule, MatIconModule} from '@angular/material';
```

you have to import like

```
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
```

Comment: While I do not know if your solution has any effect whatsoever it did help me notice the missing MatButtonModule import when I tried using the toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the styling issue and in my case it worked by just applying `color="primary"` and the code is changed

from:

```
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Delete</button>
```

to:

```
<button mat-button color="primary" [mat-dialog-close]="true">Delete</button>
```

I hope it helps someone save their time! :)

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 11, I had to import the modules in each ts file to get my styles correct. I have more details posted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65525303/249097).

Answer (score 0):

Newbie on Angular here and just in case someone else has the same error I had... I get here because I was struggling because my button didn't get the styles when I imported MatMenuModule on my app.module.ts and I didn't realized I had to import MatButtonModule as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).