# Angular Material CSS not reflecting

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 8 with angular material, though I have imported angular material css in styles.css that is included in angular.json but still Angular material CSS is not loading on my component (component is lazy loaded )

Its my angular.json code you can check I have included styles.css

```
     {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "apexx-portal-ui": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apexx-portal-ui",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "apexx-portal-ui:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "apexx-portal-ui:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "apexx-portal-ui:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "apexx-portal-ui-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "apexx-portal-ui:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "apexx-portal-ui:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "apexx-portal-ui"
}
```

this is my styles.css code where import for indigo-pink.css is done

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";

/* angular Material theme import */
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

@import './assets/styles/alertify.core.css';
@import './assets/styles/alertify.bootstrap.css';
```

Please suggest me what I am missing

Comment: check your style.css file maybe it is .scss file and you are giving wrong extension.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: You can check the following answer too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62259528/3660648

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to import angular material styles is

styles.css:

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Try it out!

Comment: My styles.css is under src folder and For me path is  @import '../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';   But its not loading CSS on front.