# Angular Material: Components not styled correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have set up a project using Angular Material 10. The components are not rendering properly as you can see in this [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vtpbkj).

I don't get any error in the console.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Did you use [`ng add @angular/material`](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) to add Material to your existing Angular project?

Comment: yes i did and i had the same issue as with my example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Material Style Class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286202/angular-material-style-class-not-working)

Comment: The way you import it is right. I tried to add  `indigo-pink.css` in your `angular.json` instead of  the `purple-green.css` and it worked.

Tried the `pink-bluegrey.css` and then, same bug but the color changed... 

I think this it may be some angular bug.

Comment: @rbalet you are right thank you! i tried a different theme and it worked. I had this setup with angular 8 and it was working fine so it's a bug indeed

Comment: @gaetann I've opened and bug report https://github.com/angular/components/issues/20716

Comment: @gaetann As say [here](github.com/angular/components/issues/20716) it isn't a bug, but the way angular display dark theme. I've updated my answer to explain how it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're way to import the css file is correct,

*edit*

### Response

But as found [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme) and also answered [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/20716#issuecomment-703770600)

> Finally, if your app's content is not placed inside of a mat-sidenav-container element, you need to add the **mat-app-background** class to your wrapper element (for example the body). This ensures that the proper theme background is applied to your page.

You have to add the `body` tag with the `mat-app=background` class to your `index.html` *or to a wrapper element around the app* to make it work [see here for the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fj2vxv?file=src%2Findex.html).

Note that if you add it to the `app` node itself, you'll also need a `display: block`

### Usefull

Angular have 3 different ways to add material theme to your app

1. Inside `angular.json` file

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
```

2. inside the `style.css` file

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

3. Inside the `index.html` file

```html
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include a theme in your `styles.css`, for example:

`@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

And include a reference to `styles.css` in `index.html` as follows:

```
<head>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Or if you prefer not using the `styles.css`, you can include the theme in the `index.html`:

```
<head>
  <link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Reference: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: I have included it in angular.json , styles. Isn't that enough ?

Comment: As I already said in my answer, in the top question. You shall import it directly into `angular.json`, it's also a correct option.